# (ngModelChange) function fires twice when using with ng DateTimePicker - Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7, datetimepicker

In Angular I'm using ng datetimepicker library to display the date time picker, but when I use (ngModelChange) on the datetimepicker, the mentioned method is firing twice at a time, the changed date is displayed twice in the console. Can anyone help in resolving this

```js
dateChange(e){
    console.log(e);
}
```

```html
<div class="fleft">
    <div class="form">
      <label for="fromDate">From Date</label>
      <date-time-picker name="fromDate" [pickerType]="pickerType" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="fromDate1"
                        [setDate]="fromDate1" (ngModelChange)="dateChange($event)"
                [reset]="resetDatePicker" [setMax]="setMax "></date-time-picker>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This may help. https://dev.to/jwp/angular-ngmodel-model-and-viewmodel-5m

Answer (score 2):

Try using `(change)="dateChange($event)"` instead of `(ngModelChange)`. Hope this will work :)